# How to handle repeated service call

Tags: android, service

I have two broadcast receivers: 1) to listen to network change 2) To listen to sqlite db modification.
Both broadcast calls same service if internet is connected.

In my service onStartCommand I'm checking whether database has any entry, if yes then request is performed in the background.
My issue is - when there is no internet, all requests are stored in db, and when connected to internet, and again any request is stored in db, then both broadcast are triggered, hence onStartCommand is called twice, so each request is also done twice. How can I avoid this? I have tried using IntentService and Service both, and both are working in similar manner.

I want that if onStartCommand is already called then it should restrict another service call. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: If you can share the code will look into that Alternate 1. your saving the requests in DB so once the request is executed delete that from DB(if you require the DB data put some boolean & handle request execution based on boolean )

Comment: You have to create a flag in your database, which indicates, if the task is already done, if done, make that flag to 1 or keep 0, on internet connected or db modified just check if there is any pending task,  call your service, else don't call.use your broadcast receivers to check the db flags and depending on the flags make decision to call the service

Comment: Create a static variable like `int whichBroadCast` triggered set it to value `1` in one broadcast receiver and value `2` in another receiver(or whatever value you like). So before triggering the service check for these values and then trigger correspondingly.

Comment: @RameshKanuganti: I'm deleting entry from db as soon as I'm getting success in response. But as the service gets call before completion of first request, it sends the request again.